# Truncate integer in C

Tags: c, integer

Is there a way to remove the last number from an integer in C? For example, if the user entered the number: "123" is there a way to change that to just "12"?

Thanks

Comment: I was gonna up-vote this because it's not a bad question, but two minutes of research on the interconnected web of computer machines would have given you the answer.

Comment: I did do some research but all I could find was stuff talking about %.3f for example for printf

Comment: A better question would have been: How do I get "23" from "123"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide that integer number by 10.

123 / 10 == 12.

Answer (score 8):

I usually just divide by 10. Integer math truncates. Usually that drives beginners mad, but it's exactly what you want here. Be mindful of negative numbers though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! And yes, working with integers always manages to throw me off as a beginner in this language. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to truncate it as an integer value just use integer division.

```
number = 123;
number /= 10;
/* number is now 12 */
```

For strings depending on how you allocated it you can just set the 3 to a `\0` character to not print it in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Dividing by 10 is definitely the preferred solution.

However, if you want to remove the last digit from an input string *before* converting to an integer (ex. if the user might enter a number too big to fit in an `int`, like 5000111222), you can do the following, assuming the user's input is in the `char *` variable `buf`:

```
buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;
```

This terminates the string one character early. Be mindful that this will produce undefined behaviour if the string is empty (`""`), so make sure the string is nonempty first.

Comment: It also removes anything after the integer, if the string continues.

Comment: Well, no, it just removes the last character unconditionally. If you were going to pass `"123 foo bar"` into `atoi`, this would turn it into `"123 foo ba"`. If you really want to remove digits from the first number in a string, you'll need a bit more sophistication.

Comment: Hmm. I like this. Thanks for the (rather different) response. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind numbers are different from their decimal representations.

That said, you can just use integer division here to divide by ten.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 10; i < 21; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", i, i/10);

    return 0;
}
```